# How to prevent current page reload and go to home page in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to redirect to home page from every page in my app. So I add the below code:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/otp" component={Otp} />
    <Layout>
      <Suspense fallback={<LayoutSplashScreen />}>
        <Redirect push to="/homePage" />
        <ContentRoute
          path="/homePage"
          component={RequestTabel}
          children={undefined}
          render={undefined}
        />
        <ContentRoute
          path="/Register"
          component={RegisterPage}
          children={undefined}
          render={undefined}
        />
         .
         .
         .
   </Layout>
</Switch>
```

Now, when I refresh every page then I go to home page but the current page reloads and after  that, the app goes to home page. I don't know why and I want to proofread it. I've searched a lot and I can the below link but I have to add it in all of my pages in the app and I think, it's not the correct solution.

```
if (performance.navigation.type === 1) {
// page was just refreshed:

window.location.href = '/homePage';
}
```

I add other parts of related code to my question:

routes.tsx

```
export default function Routes() {
 return ( 
    <Switch>
       <HashRouter>
          <BasePage />
       </HashRouter>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

`BasePage` is the above code that I've written first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is unconditionally rendering the `Redirect` component. If you would like `"/homepage"` to be a sort of "default" route then the nested routes inside `Layout`/`Suspense` should ***also*** be wrapped in a `Switch` (*the outer `Switch` will already be matching and rendering `Layout`*) and the `Redirect` moved to the end of the `Switch` as a "catch-all" route to redirect users to `"/homepage"` if they weren't trying to access any other route.

Example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route path="/otp" component={Otp} />
  <Layout>
    <Suspense fallback={<LayoutSplashScreen />}>
      <Switch>
        <ContentRoute path="/homePage" component={RequestTabel} />
        <ContentRoute path="/Register" component={RegisterPage} />
          ...
          ...
          ...
        <Redirect push to="/homePage" />
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </Layout>
</Switch>
```

If you want the app to redirect to `"/homepage"` when it mounts then add a `useEffect` hook to the first component under the router and issue an imperative redirect.

Example:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    history.replace("/homepage");
  }, []);

  ... rest of the component code
};
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thanks @Drew Reese, but with your code, the app doesn't go to home page in reloading every page.  I want to go to the home page instead reload the current page. but in my code, the current page reloads and mounts again, and after that goes to the home page. but I don't know why. Sorry if my English is weak and maybe can't get my point across.

Comment: @changeworld Can you clarify what you mean by "the app doesn't go to home page in reloading every page"? Are you saying if you navigate to `"/homepage"` or any other path you don't have a route for that the `RequestTabel` component isn't rendered? What exactly does page loading/reloading have to do with rendering the home page? Perhaps we're not understanding your issue or use case. Please try to clarify.

Comment: @changeworld Ok, I've read your comment on the other answer. *What* exactly is your code doing now that redirects to the home page? Please edit your post and provide a more complete [mcve] that includes the root app and router, routes, the component code doing the redirect, and any relevant code between these that may be relevant to the issue/question.

Comment: Thanks @Drew Reese. I have the above code in `basePage` and I don't have other codes to handle redirecting to the homepage. So, now when I click on F5, the app reloads the current page(for example pageA, with the debugger, I see start pageA from first) and then after finishing it, goes to homePage.

Comment: @changeworld If you don't have any other code to handle redirecting to the home page then what is navigating to the home page when the app is loaded/reloaded? What is `basePage` or `pageA`?

Comment: I've added other some parts of related code to my question. `basePage` manges routing between components. `pageA` means something like `Register page` or something like this. This is just an example. and `<Redirect to="/homePage" />` in above of `Layout` handle to redirect to `homePage`

Comment: @changeworld It's still unclear what & where your code is doing things, but I've updated my answer with what I'd suggest doing if you want to effect a redirect action when the app code mounts.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout simply exists, calling `Redirect` every time.
I am not sure which routing library you're using. If it is `react-router-dom`, take a look at their [documentation to route Layouts](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes). The TL;DR (though you should definitely read) is that everything in a router needs to be inside a `Route`, you can't have things being free like this.
If it is some other library, like TanStack Router try to find their definition of routing.

As it stands, your `Redirect` component is always being called, which is why you are always being redirected. It needs to be conditioned in a route.

Comment: Thanks @Ronny Efronny. I think, you can't understand my question. I want to redirect to homepage and it does it correctly but before redirect to home page, reload the current page and I don't know why the current page firstly reload and then go to home page

Comment: I don't understand what reloading means here. You either load the current page, or redirect from it, you can't have both, only one page can be active at a time. Perhaps if you added more details in the question, like what library you're using and what should triger the redirect, it would be helpful.

Comment: I used `react-router-dom` library. reload mean when the user clicks on F5 on the browser and the user wants to reload the page. In this situation, I want to go to the home page instead reload the current page. but in my code, the current page reloads and mounts again, and after that go to the home page. but I don't know why

Comment: @changeworld I understand what you mean now. In your `useEffect` you have "homepage" miscased, you use "homePage" everywhere else. Could this be the issue? If not, try to use `useLayoutEffect` instead.